# Got error on system boot, need check filesystem manually

Tags: debian, filesystems, ssd, initramfs, fsck

Debian, installed on SSD disk. On system boot got error:

```
ROOT: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck manually
(i.e. without -a or -p options)
fsck exited with status code 4.
The root filesystem on /dev/sda2 requires a manual fsck.

BysyBox v.1.22.1 (Debian 1:1.22.0-19+deb9u2) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' to a list of built-in commands
(initramfs) sudo umount /dev/sda2
sh: sudo: not found
(initramfs)
```

I tried unmount the disk first, but command fail.
How serious is this error, and what commands should I run? Can't this error to be a symptoms preceding the SSD disk failure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, don't worry! This can sometimes happen if the drive isn't unmounted cleanly (such as holding the power button) and can even happen naturally. Your data is most likely safe.

You won't have `sudo` in the live initramfs environment, as `sudo` isn't usually integrated into it. You would be running as the root user at this point, so `sudo` isn't needed.

Try a plain `umount /dev/sda2` and then `fsck /dev/sda2`.

If this still doesn't work, for whatever reason, I'd suggest booting into a Live Linux Environment and running `fsck` that way.

Comment: I tried: `umount /dev/sda2` `umount: can't umount /dev/sda2: Invalid argument`

Comment: @LexxLuxx then it is probably not mounted (which is what I'd expect anyway). So go ahead and try `fsck /dev/sda2`.

Comment: confirm (y) for each error?

Comment: Yes, this should fix everything and allow you to boot normally afterwards.

Comment: Of course, it _can_ be a symptom of an impending drive failure...

Answer (score 6):

You cannot unmount a *root* filesystem, since then there would be nothing to mount `/dev` on, and nothing to load the `fsck` command from.

Checking the *root* filesystem is a special case: you can do it when the root filesystem is mounted **read-only**, and if the filesystem check makes any changes, you must reboot immediately after `fsck` is complete.

Since you are within an initramfs, the root filesystem is probably already in read-only mode, and you can proceed with the filesystem check.

Comment: @brxken This helped. For whatever reason `reboot` command at the (initramfs) command prompt not worked for me. I used `exit`, and this caused reboot to the debian login prompt. Thank you.

Comment: @LexxLuxx If you're curious, the reason `reboot` failed was because the normal `init` process (or `systemd`) was not running yet: the limited version running in initramfs may not handle a normal `reboot` request. On the other hand, `reboot -f` or `reboot -ff` should work - and in fact is one of the few places where it can legitimately be used. But as you saw, just `exit` will usually reboot automatically if you were dropped into emergency shell because of `fsck` issues.